# Create instance from behavior of a list

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a behavior to support selectedItems in a listbox. And here is part of the code.
Is there a way if target aka  **AssociatedObject.SelectedItems** is null to create an instance of it? All I tried failed...

```
void ContextSelectedItems_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Need to unsubscribe from the events so we don't override the transfer
    UnsubscribeFromEvents();
         
    //Move items from the selected items list to the list box selection
    Transfer(SelectedItems as IList,  AssociatedObject.SelectedItems);
         
    //subscribe to the events again so we know when changes are made
    SubscribeToEvents();
}

public static void Transfer(IList source,  IList target)
{
    if (source == null || target == null)
    {
        return;
    }
         
    target.Clear();
         
    foreach (var o in source)
    {
       target.Add(o);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here is where my code is coming from.  http://blog.bdcsoft.com/developer-blog/2011/no-binding-for-you-a-listbox-selecteditems-behavior-solution/

Answer (score 1):

This might be easier than you think now that mathieu said why your code doesn't work. Try something like the code below.

HTH,
Berryl

```
void ContextSelectedItems_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
//Need to unsubscribe from the events so we don't override the transfer
UnsubscribeFromEvents();

//Move items from the selected items list to the list box selection
Transfer(SelectedItems as IList,  AssociatedObject);

//subscribe to the events again so we know when changes are made
SubscribeToEvents();
}

public static void Transfer(IList source,  ListBox lb)
{
    if (source == null || lb== null || !lb.SelectedItems.Any())
        return;
}
lb.SetSelectedItems(source)
}
```

Comment: i updated the question with the link.The problem isnt that it doesnt work,it does.But if target is null then i dont know if it is possible to create a new instance from this code.  <local:MultiSelectBehavior SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedListOfItems}" />   I mean SelectedListOfItems  if null to be  created somehow and not having to create instance manually outside from the behavior

Comment: @Parhs. There are guards in the code for the target being null. Are you getting an error? Post the error if so....

Comment: no i dont get error. I mean suppose you have a product object that has a preferences property which is a collection. If this property is nullo then the code wont work because it is null. I was wondering in that case if it is possible to create a new instance so it can work automatically

Comment: @Parhs. I *guess* anything is possible if you are motivated enough, if not all within the behavior, but what is the motivating use case here?? More pragmatically, under what circumstances might the property be null and the user needs a new instance?? Maybe its a YAGNI!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a value to the SelectedItems property of a ListBox, as it is a readonly property : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selecteditems(v=vs.110).aspx

```
[BindableAttribute(true)]
public IList SelectedItems { get; }
```

Use [SetSelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.setselecteditems.aspx) method for that.

Also, the SelectedItems property should not be null on a ListBox, but an empty list.

Comment: it is a behavior. http://blog.bdcsoft.com/developer-blog/2011/no-binding-for-you-a-listbox-selecteditems-behavior-solution/  .However the collection should be initialised :(

Comment: @Parhs. Yes, it is a behavior and yes, mathieu is telling you what is wrong. See sample code I posted. Cheers